# Show $f^{-1}(0)$ is a regular surface

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I'm not sure what to do in this problem. I'm given the function $f(x,y,z)=z^2$ I have to show that 0 is not a regular value (which I've already done) and show that $f^{-1}(0)$ is a regular surface. I can't do this last part. I don't know what to use.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you describe the level surface $f^{-1}(0)$...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{-1}(0)=\{(x,y,z): z^2=z=0\}$ so it is a plane.